Unit tests are no longer pulling from properties file for object instantiation and resulting in null pointers. I'm running mvn test goal in intellij
After upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17, Junit 4 to Junit5, and updating my projects dependencies for compatibility some of my unit tests are failing because my AuthenticationProperties class is not being instantiated with values. It pulls from properties file using @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dealer-imagery-api.authentication") and works fine when reverting completely back to the old set up. It has a nested User class that should pick up those properties. Weird thing is is that when I run the mvn test goal through intellij they fail but running them by right clicking the package and running tests (after editing configurtion to use VM option to decrypt passwords) they pass. Can anyone help me identify the root cause?
I have another module that I upgraded to Java 17 and Junit 5 and after making the necessary changes, mainly the junit annotations, and running the tests using mvn test goal through intellij they pass. For some reason my properties aren't being used in my tests. I have a properties file in main/java/resources and expected mvn to use that properties file when running tests. I tried copying over the properties file into test/java/resources but that didn't work. My tests before didn't have to have that file there when running the tests.
package com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dealer-imagery-api.authentication")
public class AuthenticationProperties {

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", AuthenticationProperties.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("users=" + users)
                .toString();
    }

    public static class User {

        private String username;
        private String password;
        private List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        private String owner;

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public List<String> getAuthorities() {
            return authorities;
        }

        public void setAuthorities(List<String> authorities) {
            this.authorities = authorities;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public void setOwner(String owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", User.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                    .add("username='" + username + "'")
                    .add("password='********'")
                    .add("authorities=" + authorities)
                    .add("owner='" + owner + "'")
                    .toString();
        }
    }
}


package com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AuthenticationPropertiesTest {
    private AuthenticationProperties instance;
    private AuthenticationProperties.User user;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        instance = new AuthenticationProperties();
        user = new AuthenticationProperties.User();
        ArrayList<AuthenticationProperties.User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(user);
        instance.setUsers(users);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetGetUsers() {
        List<AuthenticationProperties.User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add("user");
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        users.add(user);
        instance.setUsers(users);
        Assertions.assertEquals(users, instance.getUsers(), "Invalid property [users]");
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        instance.toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetGetUsername() {
        user.setUsername("username");
        Assertions.assertEquals("username", user.getUsername(), "Invalid property [username]");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetGetPassword() {
        user.setPassword("password");
        Assertions.assertEquals("password", user.getPassword(), "Invalid property [password]");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetGetAuthorities() {
        List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add("user");
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        Assertions.assertEquals(authorities, user.getAuthorities(), "Invalid property [authorities]");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetGetOwner() {
        user.setOwner("owner");
        Assertions.assertEquals("owner", user.getOwner(), "Invalid property [owner]");
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserToString() {
        user.toString();
    }
}

Failed tests:   com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationPropertiesTest.testSetGetAuthorities(): Cannot invoke "com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationProperties$User.setAuthorities(java.util.List)" because "this.user" is null
  com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationPropertiesTest.testSetGetUsername(): Cannot invoke "com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationProperties$User.setUsername(String)" because "this.user" is null
  com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationPropertiesTest.testSetGetPassword(): Cannot invoke "com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationProperties$User.setPassword(String)" because "this.user" is null
  com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationPropertiesTest.testUserToString(): Cannot invoke "com.gm.gsmc.dealerimagery.config.AuthenticationProperties$User.toString()" because "this.user" is null


General advice: First upgrade java, make everything work. Then upgrade Junit or any other dependencies. Don't do two or more upgrades at once.
